# How to analyze the relationship between two continuous variables beyond regression and EDA?

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I have two continuous variables (net_profit and duration_of_operation) and I want to examine relationships between these. So far, I've done regression analysis, hierarchical clustering, correlation analysis, and EDA in R, but are there other avenues I can try?

Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Always start by plotting some visualizations. Then you may develop an intuition for the problem.

On the face of things, profit should approximately scale linearly with duration, so what you probably want to do is plot the residuals from a linear regression. I suspect that what your client actual wants is an understanding these residuals.